# Behavior of flex-box when position is absolute

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hey guys can you look at following code and explain me why flexbox is behaving in this manner.

1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body{
            position: relative;
        }
        .container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="item"> hello</div>
    <div class="item"> hi</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

2. 

```
.container {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
```

3. 

```
.container {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right:0;
            top: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
```

I was expecting that flex-box would automatically take full width given justify-content: space-between; Normally it works but when I make position of the container it doesn't take full width and I have to force it.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a div, it takes the full width, so the justify-content works but when you add position absolute, it takes the width of its content.

So you need to specify the width as you did, then the justify content will take full width:

```
.container {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right:0;
            top: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
```

or just give it :

```
.container {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
```